# How to perform user input in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been struggling for a while on this (been reading a lot of the ruby on rail guides to try and understand this), but I'm not sure how user inputs work.

I am trying to search for a restaurant in my database with a list of fields the user specifies (cuisine, zipcode, review score). I have created a html.erb page that has the options for all of these.

Here is my controller.

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
        def home
            @my_search = Restaurant.joins(:inspection).where(cuisine: c, zipcode: z, totalscore: 1..h)
        end
```

My models for restaurant and inspection also have relations between them (the foreign keys).

How would you go about letting the user give inputs for c (cuisine), z (zipcode) and 1..h (score range)?

I know that people have answered this question in the past, but I think I need a concrete example to actually understand how to do this. As in, what would you put in the html.erb code so that when an option is selected, that value is passed to the method?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to create a form in the view. The simplest way to do this is with form_tag:

```
<%= form_tag(home_path) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'cuisine' %>
  ...other inputs
<% end %>
```

Next, make sure you have a route defined for your controller action in config/routes.rb

```
post 'home' => 'welcome#home'
```

Most likely your routes will look different but this is the bare minimum you need.

And in your controller you can access the submitted data using the params object

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @restaurants = Restaurant.joins(:inspection).where(
      cuisine: params[:cuisine],
      # ...other params
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: When I try just using that erb code

<html>
<%= form_tag(home_path) %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'cuisine' %>
  ...other inputs
<% end %>
</html>

I get an error saying synthax error expecting $end
is there any reason for this?

Comment: Oh sorry I made a typo. Its missing the do. I'll update it now.

Comment: You are a life saver. I've finally understood how to do this. Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries! I'm on Codementor too if you ever need more help.